# How to play mp3 file in listbox and button?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I play mp3 file in listbox and button? I'm tried too much but I couldn't. When Im clicked button 1-2 and listbox my codes break.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media1.Play();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        media1.Stop();
    }

    private void listbox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        media1.Play();
    }

    private void btn010_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog open1 = new  Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        open1.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
        open1.Filter = "(.mp3)|*.mp3";
        open1.Multiselect = true;

        Nullable<bool> result = open1.ShowDialog();

        if(result == true)
        {
          for ( int i = 0; i < open1.SafeFileNames.Length; i++)
          {
              listbox4.Items.Add(open1.SafeFileNames[i].ToString());
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code:

You never set the Source of what I'm presuming is a MediaElement:

```
private void listbox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //This plays the MediaElement, but it doesn't have a Source to play yet!
    //media1.Play();

    //Instead, let's set the Source:
    if (listbox4.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        media1.Source = new Uri(listbox4.SelectedItem.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
}
```

You've used SafeFileNames, which only provides the *file name* (e.g. MyFile.mp3), not the *path* (e.g. C:\Music\MyFile.mp3) that MediaElement needs. You have to use FileNames to get the full path.

```
private void btn010_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog open1 = new  Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    open1.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    open1.Filter = "(.mp3)|*.mp3";
    open1.Multiselect = true;

    Nullable<bool> result = open1.ShowDialog();

    if(result == true)
    {
        //Can't get the full path from SafeFileNames:
        //for ( int i = 0; i < open1.SafeFileNames.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    listbox4.Items.Add(open1.SafeFileNames[i].ToString());
        //}

        //Instead, we get the full path from FileNames:
        for ( int i = 0; i < open1.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            listbox4.Items.Add(open1.FileNames[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

That should render your program functional. If you want it to auto play through the track list you'll need to handle the MediaElement's MediaEnded event:

```
private void media1_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //If a track finishes, check if there are more tracks and 
    //increment to the next one if so.
    if (listbox4.Items.Count > listbox4.SelectedIndex + 1)
    {
        listbox4.SelectedIndex++;
        media1.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but how can i play / stop media ? With media1.Play/Stop();?

Comment: Take the code you posted in your question. Replace the listbox4_SelectionChanged and btn010_Click methods with those posted in my answer. Add the media1_MediaEnded method to the end of the C# code, then add MediaEnded="media1_MediaEnded" to your MediaElement XAML. That *should* work, but I can't guarantee it as you haven't posted any XAML.